# Creating unique sequential bank account numbers without dead lock and race condition

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, deadlock

I need to create a unique account number for users signing up on my web application. The account number will be created by incrementing the numbers

```
user 1 - 9898000000001
user 2 - 9898000000002
...
```

I have the following stored procedure in MySQL database

```
consider bank_id as '9898' below.

BEGIN
  Set @initialComId = '0000001';
  Set @table_value = null;
  Set @t = null;
SELECT max(company_va) into @table_value FROM virtual_account_numbers
IF ((@table_value) is null and bank_id =1) then
Set @newComId = CONCAT(bank_id,'000001');
INSERT INTO virtual_account_numbers (company_va,partner_banks_id)VALUES (@newComId,bank_id);
SELECT company_va from virtual_account_numbers ORDER BY virtual_account_numbers_id DESC LIMIT 1;                         
END
```

With the above-stored procedure, I am running into a dead lock if 10 users register at the same time.

Is there a better solution to this? The account number cannot be random generated number and should be incremented ones.

Comment: Let the database do it, eg. use AUTO_INCREMENT

Comment: Yes, my idea too, see: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp

Comment: @LarsStegelitzThanks. But will I be able to achieve 00000001, 00000002 using auto increments?

Comment: Yes you will. you might have to add the zeros in front, when needed, but yes.

Comment: MySQL function LPAD will do the padding...

Answer (score 0):

All together:

- Let the database manage the sequence via AUTO_INCREMENT
- Use LPAD to fill up with Zeros. Example with 1 : LPAD('1', 10, '0') = 0000000001
- Write the new account number into a VARCHAR field

To aid a search, put an INDEX on the account number field.